# Render quality falls blurry and blocky with longer lens length

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, resolution

I'm using EEVEE. When I change the lens length of my camera from, say, 28mm to 200mm, most of the scene becomes blocky and blurry — not in a photographic way, but in a low-resolution way. Some of the scene is still sharp with high-resolution textures and edges, but much of it is unusable.

If I switch the camera to a shorter lens length, everything renders beautifully, but I need the optical behavior of a longer lens.

I'm assuming there is something basic I'm overlooking that addresses this.

Edited to add:

[image: 28mm vs. 200mm comparison]

The only thing that's changed is the camera lens length (and the position of the camera, which had to be pushed forward for the 28mm lens).

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. :) Seriously, though, please post a picture of good vs. bad so we can get a better idea of the issue(s) you're facing.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Literally the last thing that went through my head was that I have to take some screenshots before I post this...right before I posted without screenshots.

Comment: My first guess would be Z-fighting because of floating-point error: the clipping-range not accommodating the distance-range comfortably? Try adjusting the near and far clip of the camera to whatever is suitable for the 200mm distance.